# How to get the type of deserialized C# object from JSON text?

Tags: c#, .net, json, wcf, json.net

I am trying to get the type of serialized C# object in JSON Text ( $type in JSON text)   without deserialising  the JSON text to object again . can you please suggest what are all the option do i have?

I am using Newtonsoft library for serialization and serialization.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its fairly simple using the Newtonsoft library.

```
JObject json = JObject.Parse(JsonText);
string type = json["$type"].ToString();
```

Comment: I *thought* you wanted to achieve this without parsing the text back to an object again?  Hence the get token idea.  If performance is an issue for you, the solution I posted will serve you better.  Perhaps you discovered it doesn't matter very much in the scheme of things, which is often the case.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use Newtonsoft library.  However, assuming that $type is either at the start of the file or at the end I'd probably use string functions (psudocode below) which'd be quite fast.

- find $type
- i=find next colon
- j=find next comma
- grab token between i and j
- trim that token
- do something useful with the token.  Make a type out of it with reflection?

How does that sound?  While you are at it you could write an extension method.  Hit +1 several times and I'll think about writing the code ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I solved it using Newtonsoft libaray and posted the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 var jsonObj = JObject.Parse("your json string");
 var props = jsonObj.Properties();

 foreach (var prop in props)
 {
     Console.WriteLine(prop.Value.Type);
 }
```

I hope this help you!